# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'dimple' with Middleman and Bower

Tags: bower, sprockets, middleman

config.rb:

```
ready do
  sprockets.append_path File.join root, 'bower_components'
end
```

application.coffee:

```
//= require 'dimple'
//= require 'director'
```

When I access to or build a js file which is served by Middleman + Sprockets, some modules installed through Bower return a not-found error. jQuery etc works normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently some Bower modules are not Sprockets compatible. I needed to set a full path while jQuery requires only its name.

```
//= require 'jquery'
//= require 'dimple/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.js'
//= require 'director/build/director.js'
//= require 'spinjs/spin.js'
```

Comment: FYI, i ended up not using Bower directly with Middleman. Too many JS libs violate the Bower's recommendation to bundle only dist files and not everything they've got in the repo. So i set the `bower_components` module to ignore in Middleman's `config.rb` and use a grunt-copy task to copy hand-picked files into the `javascripts/vendor` folder.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov Can you share your grunt-copy task? Thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lolmaus/56f64698d3fc81547b69 https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy